# changes need in server for enabling soap request for https

Tags: php, http, soap

I have a soap request for https url,
I have the password, and the pem file.

but some how when I run the script, it stops where Im trying to make the connection,
and it doesnt even display an error....

do you have any suggestions??

one more thing:
when I access my server threw remote connection and try to enter the url threw the browser,
it cant find the page, but in my other server the currently works with the soap request, it asks me for the location of the pem file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the connection is not being authorized but I would need more information (seeing some code would definitely help).One thought, is your server a Windows box? If so, SOAP requires the full path to the certificate file like "C:\htdocs\mycert.pem".